# Rewrite URL with .htaccess but 404 error occur

Tags: javascript, mysql, seo, google-search

currently i have made a website which can call data from MySQL database then fit everything into the pre-made HTML template. So basically I am using the follow link:https://gttutor.com/tutor-profile/?GTnum=2701. All the query are searched based on the number after "?" i.e 2701. Yet I found that through this method there wouldnt be an individual website for each profile and hence not searchable in google search engine. May I know how can i overcome this issue? Thanks!

For the follow up discussion

I want:

```
demo.com/profile/GTnum/2706
```

being read as:

```
demo.com/profile/?GTnum=2706
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^GTnum/(\d+)$    ?GTnum=$1 [L]
```

Comment: *"there wouldnt be an individual website for each profile and hence not searchable in google search engine"* — I would research this basic assumption; most search engines handle this kind of URL just fine.

Comment: @deceze Hi Deceze hope this find u well, I have tried multiple time but still couldn't fix the issue. May u give me some guidance on chaing /?GTnum=2701 -> sth like /GTnum/2701 so i can make all the similar page public in google search engine? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you read the duplicate linked at the top of the page?

Comment: @deceze Yes so now i have changed the URL in my website to tutor-profile/GTnum/2706 and would like to use .htaccess to write it in tutor-profile/?GTnum=2706 so the php code can still run. I tried the following but it doesnt work, did I do anything wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^GTnum/(\d+)$    ?GTnum=$1 [L]
```